# how to create new rows using jquery datatable drawcallback

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using jquery datatable to create table grid on my web page, for that i want to add new rows with grouping columns. below is my requirement

```
transactiondetails
    customer
        customer1
        customer2
activity
    activity1
other
customer
  customer1
  customer1

"drawCallback": function (settings, json) {
            debugger;
           `enter code here` var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var last = null;
            var catLast = null;

            api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                if (last !== group) {
                    $(rows).eq(i).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5"><strong>' + group + '</strong></td></tr>' 

                    );

                    last = group;

                    api.column(1, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {

                        if (catLast !== group && group === 'Agent') {
                                $(rows).eq(i).before(
                                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5"><strong>' + group + '</strong></td></tr>'

                                );
                                catLast = group;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```